# How to add a checkbox to each search result?

Tags: 2010, search-results

I have a requirement for the user to be able to save selected search results. The design calls for a checkbox to be added alongside each result and a "Save" button at the bottom which does the actual saving of all the "checked" results.

For this to look nice, I think the checkbox should be in a separate column.

Can this be done by modifying the XSLT of the CoreResultsWebPart or do I need to extend the CoreResultsWebPart?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require a custom results page and part in my head for the following reasons:

(It looks like a search results favorites page?)

1. Results saved would need to be stored into a list somehow.
2. Results would also have to be retrieved.
3. The check box would need to be linked and created from the post

This is all very simple to do and to achieve, once the user experience has been nailed down.

I would use the full text query perhaps for the search results and there are plenty of articles on how to build results pages from these queries.

No more than about a days work if you have experience with working with the search API, 3 days at the most if you don't for coding time + testing time depending on your project management methodology.